# Firebase rules - How to block extra data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I checked the documentation and many other sources, but I couldn't find any information related to this.
How do you make sure the data is being sent by the user does not have extra data?

Let's say, a post could be
`{ title: 'Y', author: X, content: 'lorem...' }`

Is there any way you can make sure that the user is not including anything more than the title, the author and the content? How do we stop those cases and secure the database so it does not include anything more than what is expected?

I mean, sure, you can handle that from the front-end side...but that's not secure :)

The only way I found to handle that is by using Cloud Functions and setting there the necessary rules/logic.

---

*Furthermore*, It gives me the feeling that Firestore rules are not as secure as they should be.
Unless you just set up rules for reading content, not writing, as it seems you can't stop the user adding extra data (props).

I hope someone can give a bit of light to this subject :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict keys by firestore rules, but you need to update rules every time you add new keys, try the following rule

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /scenarios/{scenario} {//replace scenarios with your collection name
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(['title','author','content']) == true;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had the feeling I was definitely missing something.
A bit more of rules documentation (or more extended) is needed (imo) :)